# Does "maximum" stand before or after a number?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

In a table of different values, I wonder where to put the "max.":
(max. 5000) *or* (5000 max.)

I feel like one of those two should sound more idiomatic, but I am not sure which one. Or do you think it's the same?

Comment: If it's just "5000 max" in a cell in a table it doesn't matter what is grammatical, and you should consider which looks better or is easier to read. This would depend on the context, what else is in the table, if all entries are maximums, or max/min, or ranges, or what else. If you're appending with a unit or item, then max would normally go before e.g. "max. 5000 people", "max 500 g", but you also see the reverse "500 g max".

Comment: Are you using "maximum" as a noun or an adjective?

Comment: Thank you, Stuart, good to know :)

Comment: @HotLicks as an adjective, and I think Stuart's answer summed it up nicely.

Comment: Note that max is often, perhaps usually, used without the period where not otherwise required.

Answer (score 1):

Max. with the period at the end would indicate that you are shortening the word for convenience.

The word max is an informal [Lexico; Collins for the 'British usage'] or slang [AHD; Collins for the 'American usage'] word that is a whole word in itself.  It could mean maximum (n. and adv.), maximal (adj.), or maximally (adv.).

When you say "5000 max", you're using the adverb form of max, and could be read as "5000 maximum" or "5000 maximally."

> Example from AHD, who only license the 'maximally' expansion:  *We'll
> pay $250 max*.

When you say "max 5000", it would probably mean a "maximum of 5000".

References: [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, 5th ed.](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=max),

Oxford English Dictionary

Comment: *5000 max* looks like a very common abbreviation for *5000 maximum* to me, I don't see that it uses an adverb.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark
I was looking for an adverb and the the American Heritage Dictionary referance pointed only to maximally as an adverb. However, I see that the OED lists maximum as an adverb  (in addition to noun and adjective forms.) So max in "500 max" could be read as 5000 maximum or 5000 maximally. Editing my answer to make this addition/change. Thank you.

Comment: @Johnny - *So max in "500 max" could be read as 5000 maximum or 5000 maximally.* It can also be read as *5,000 **as a maximum*** = adjectival prepositional phrase.

Comment: @Greybeard - Yes, you're right. And there could be other possibilities, "5000 maximum" seems to be the simplest one.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark"
> 5000 max looks like a very common abbreviation for 5000 maximum to me, I don't
> see that it uses an adverb.

When one says, "I will pay 5000 max", I see max being used as an adverb there, to "pay". That is the reason I looked  for an adverb form of maximum. Since both maximum and maximally fit in that form, I agree on your take that 5000 max is just a common abbreviation for 5000 maximum .

Comment: I've tried to sort out what came from which reference. It's important to cite and attribute precisely (dictionaries may disagree on say POSs) and to link precisely where linking is an option. // I've got to put 'max' in the 'limiting modifiers' or 'focus particles' category, which I don't like seeing as a subset of adverbs. 'I'll pay only/no more than/just $250 /// $250 max.'

Comment: Maybe you could call it an appositive of two terms that could appear in either order.

Answer (score 0):

To me they mean something slightly different.

If there is a rule, human or physical, that defines an upper limit then I would say maximum £500, for exmple.

If I were making an estimate I might say it will take me three hours max., but this doesn't imply there is any restriction, it is just my current belief that it will take me 3 hours or less.

If your table has a list, for example of temperature readings, and you want to indicate the warmest day, I would put (max) in brackets after the number. This indicates that it is, as a matter of fact, the highest number recorded.